# Linkedin ios SDK createSessionWithAuth update error

Tags: ios, sdk, single-sign-on, linkedin-api

I'm trying to integrate the latest Linkedin SDK for iOS.

When I request createSessionWithAuth I get an alert view with the text: "You need to update the LinkedIn App in order to connect with LinkedIn"

I copied the code straight out of the sample app.

```
[LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION, nil]
                                     state:@"some state"
                    showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES
                              successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {

                                  NSLog(@"%s","success called!");
                                  LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
                                  NSLog(@"value=%@ isvalid=%@",[session value],[session isValid] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
                                  NSMutableString *text = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:[session.accessToken description]];
                                  [text appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@",state=\"%@\"",returnState]];
                                  NSLog(@"Response label text %@",text);

                              }
                                errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                    NSLog(@"%s %@","error called! ", [error description]);
                                }
 ];
```

Comment: And just to be certain here, are you sure you have the latest version of the LinkedIn iOS app installed on your device?

Comment: absolutely sure its the latest version. even deleted LinkedIn and reinstalled from the Australian store to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was experiencing the exact same issue, I checked on LinkedIn developer website to instal the SDK again and the version 1.0.3 is not available to download anymore.

Remove the framework, download and use the sdk version 1.0.2 and it will work.

Cheers.